# C++ console application to turn on and off an Arduino LED

Tags: c++, arduino, serial-port

I am trying to program an interface between the c++ console and the Arduino uno. I want to send a char or an integer via the serial port to the arduino. I have written some code (see below) and the LED blinks for a very short time. I want it to stay on until I type in another letter or number. How can this be done? I used the SerialClass.h and SerialClass.cpp from the [Arduino playground](http://playground.arduino.cc/Interfacing/CPPWindowshttp://playground.arduino.cc/Interfacing/CPPWindows). A few hours of google-fu were to no avail.

Here is the c++ code (Arduino code is below):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include "SerialClass.h"    // Library described above
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

bool weiter = true;

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    cout << "Welcome to the serial test app!\n\n" << endl;

    Serial* SP = new Serial("COM4");    // adjust as needed

    if (SP->IsConnected())
    //printf("We are connected\n");
    cout << "We are connected!\n" << endl;
    char sendingData[256] = "";
    int dataLength = 256;
    int writeResult = 0;

while (weiter == true) {
if (SP->IsConnected()) {


    cout << "Press o to turn LED on! Press anything else to turn LED off! " << endl;
    cin >> sendingData;
    writeResult = SP->WriteData(sendingData, dataLength);
    cout << "Data send: " << sendingData << endl;
}

}
return 0;
}
```

Here is the Arduino code:

```
int incomingByte = 0;   // for incoming serial data
int led = 13;
void setup() {
    Serial.begin(9600);     // opens serial port, sets data rate to 9600 bps
    pinMode(led, OUTPUT);
    Serial.println("This is my LED program; press o to turn on the LED");
}

void loop() {

    // send data only when you receive data:
    if (Serial.available() > 0) {
            // read the incoming byte:
            incomingByte = Serial.read();

            // say what you got:
            //Serial.print("I received: ");
            //Serial.println(incomingByte, DEC);

            if (incomingByte == 111) //111 entspricht dem Buchstaben o
            {
              digitalWrite(led, HIGH);
              Serial.print("I received: ");
              Serial.println(incomingByte, DEC);
              Serial.println("LED is turned on");
                            }
            if (incomingByte != 111)
            { digitalWrite(led, LOW);
              Serial.print("I received: ");
              Serial.println(incomingByte, DEC);
              Serial.println("LED is turned off");




    }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`cin` is line-buffered. This means that you only get data when you press enter. And enter is also a character. usually `0x0a` or `'\n'`. And this is not `o` so your led turns off.

What i would do is make your arduino ignore whitespace by:

```
if(incomingByte == `\n` || incomingByte == `\r` || incomingbyte == ' ')
  return;
```

What also happens is that you send 256 character every time, because your `dataLength` is never changed. So do something smart with `srtlen` ;).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks David for your comment on my question.
I found the answer by myself. I used `serial.WriteData("o",1);`

Here is the complete code of my main.cpp. Just in case it might be useful for others:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include "SerialClass.h"    // Library described above
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;


bool weiter = true;
int dummy1 = 0;


int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[]) {


cout << "*** This is my Arduino LED app! ***\n" << endl;
//Serial* SP = new Serial("COM4");
//Serial serial("COM4");
Serial serial("COM4");

if (serial.IsConnected())
//printf("We are connected\n");
cout << "We are connected!\n" << endl;



while (weiter == true) {

cout << "Press 1 for LED on; press 0 for LED off!" << endl;
cin >> dummy1;
if (dummy1 == 1) {



if (serial.IsConnected()){
    serial.WriteData("o",1);
    cout << "LED is on!" << endl;
    cout << "Do you want to continue? 1 for continue, 0 for exit!" << endl;
    //printf("\nData sent successfully!\n");
     cin >> weiter;
 }
 }


else {

    serial.WriteData("p", 1 );
    cout << "LED is off!" << endl;
    cout << "Do you want to continue? 1 for continue, 0 for exit!" << endl;
    cin >> weiter;
  }
  }

if (weiter == 1)
{
    weiter = true;
}

if (weiter == 0) {
    weiter = false;
return 0;
}
}
```

Comment: I'm getting this error when I try to compile: "error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall Serial::Serial(char const *)" (??0Serial@@QAE@PBD@Z) referenced in function _wmain". I created an empty project in VS 2019. Configuration Properties > Advanced has "Character Set" set to "Use Unicode Character Set", and Linker > System has "SubSystem" set to "Console (/SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE)". Are there any other project settings that I need to double-check?